# Dimmer that takes LED from 0 to 50 W over a defined time-period

Tags: led, timer, dimmer

I have installed a 50 W LED lamp next to my bed and plugged it into a timer, so it works as a light supplement to my alarmclock.
I love the intensity of the light, but I would like to have it fade from darkness to full brightness over 30-60 seconds to let my eyes adjust to the light slowly.
Is there a product I can buy that lets me do this? Or could someone explain to me in simple terms how to build it?

P.S. I live in Denmark with a 230V wall-output.

Comment: Without knowing the internal circuitry of your LED lamp it is impossible to design a dimmer for it.

Comment: [Reposting the same question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/623232/timer-fade-led-lamp) isn't going to magically make it on-topic. There are no 'simple terms' which would describe how to build a mains-powered dimmer like you want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should discover if this lamp has any brightness control or is dimmable. If yes, then you should get or create such control device. If not, you should modify its internal power supply circuit to add soft-start feature to it.