# Timer fade LED lamp

Tags: led, timer, dimmer

I have installed a 50 W LED lamp next to my bed and plugged it into a timer, so it works as a light supplement to my alarmclock. I love the intensity of the light, but I would like to have it fade from darkness to full brightness over 30-60 seconds to let my eyes adjust to the light slowly. How can I build a circuit that lets me both fade the power in and specify the duration from 0 to 100 %?